# Extjs Grid - Add class to row when click a cell of row

Tags: extjs, grid, cell, extjs4.1

I want to add class to row when i click a cell of grid like below

I try three option but not working. How to make it work thanks

```
listeners: {
        ,'cellclick': function (grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts ) {
            // addclass to row
            Ext.fly(grid.getView().getRow(rowIndex)).addClass('bluerow'); // not working
            grid.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'bluerow'); // not working
            Ext.get(e.target).addClass('bluerow'); // not working
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> grid param in cellclick is already a view.Please have a look [cellclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick)
>     You can do add css directly as :

```
grid.addRowCls(rowIndex, 'bluerow');
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/G3hLJ/47/)**

Comment: To removeRowCls i using grid.removeRowCls and it work. But what for grid.getRowCls ?

Comment: @freestyle if you mean about getRowClass(), you must override it yourself. check extjs docs.

Comment: @freestyle I use removeRowCls() but it doesn't work. could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code snippet:

```
grid.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex,'bluerow'); 
grid.getView().removeRowCls(rowIndex,'bluerow');
```