# How to change row background color on basis of row data of grid in Sencha ExtReact?

Tags: extjs, grid

I want to change row background on basis of row data in ExtReact grid, I couldn't find any option in the documentation

Comment: Use `grid.addRowCls(rowIndex, 'red');`

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461363/extjs-grid-add-class-to-row-when-click-a-cell-of-row

Comment: Thanks for response, but I can't use this solution. I don't want to change row background after rendering, I want to set some CSS class or background style while rendering rows. Actually there are four status for records and depending on the status I want those rows to be coloured. In Extjs 4, we can do it using 
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams) {
         //Set CSS on basis of data
    }
}

but I can't find anything like this in ExtReact 6.5.1 or Extjs 6.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Ext.grid.feature.RowBody](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.grid.feature.RowBody.html#method-getAdditionalData).  You have to override the `getAdditionalData` method and return an object that contains your `rowBodyCls`.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  ...
  features: [{
    ftype: 'rowbody',
    getAdditionalData: function (data, idx, record, orig) {
        // Use the data/record to determine which class to apply, then
        // style the row body in CSS.
        return {
            rowBodyCls: "my-body-class"
        };
    }
  }],
...
```

Comment: Thanks Joe Holloway. This solution will work for Extjs but I was looking same for ExtReact

Comment: Doh, I thought it would be the same. I will leave this in case someone is looking for ExtJS solution. I poked around in ExtReact documentation and it seems like there is some undocumented stuff similar to what I proposed here but I couldn't pinpoint exactly how to pull it off.

Comment: Thanks for the help